# Is it possible to call a fixture in the middle of running test?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fixtures

I'm newbie with fixtures in python and I have a few questions which I couldn't understand from the documentation.
I want to call a specific fixture and parameterize it in the middle of the test.Is it possible?How can I do this?
Another question is when I have a request when defining a fixture and a subrequest when I defining a class, can I get request's attributes if I only have the subrequest instance?